# Python Flet Current View/Page

Tags: python, flet

I'm working on a Python Flet project and I'm looking for resources on developing a splash screen for my desktop application. I found some resources in the Flet documentation regarding page.splash, but my requirements are different. I was able to successfully implement the splash screen part using button clicks and routing, but I don't want my users to have to click on start. I want them to navigate directly to the home screen after a certain amount of time.

I tried to call a function inside one of the pages which acts as a view, but it doesn't have the ft.Page parameter, so I'm not able to use that feature. I also tried to create the splash screen by using the sleep() function and calling a function with the event, but that didn't work either. Is there any way I can achieve this, or how can I find out which view is currently at the top?

Main Page

```
import flet as ft
from flet import *
import time

from pages.index import _view_ as v1
from pages.home import _view_ as v2
from pages.contact import _view_ as v3
from pages.index import page_nav

def master(page=ft.Page):
    page.title="Routing"
    page.window_height=250
    page.window_width=250
    page.window_center()
    index=v1()
    home=v2()
    contact=v3()

    def route_change(route):
        page.views.clear()
        if page.route == "/home":
            page.window_visible=True
            page.update()
            page.window_maximized=True
            page.views.append(home)
             
        if page.route == "/contact":
            page.views.append(contact)
        if page.route == "/index":
            page.views.append(index)
        
        page.update()

    def view_pop(view):
        page.views.pop()
        top_view=page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)

    page.on_route_change=route_change
    page.on_view_pop=view_pop
    page.go(page.route)

    page.views.append(contact)
    page.views.append(home)
    page.views.append(index)
    page.update()

ft.app(target=master)
```

My splash Page

```
from flet import View
import flet as ft
from flet import *
import random
import time

rand_clr=random.randint(000000,999999)


time.sleep(3)

page_nav(e)


def page_nav(e):
    e.page.window_visible=False
    e.page.update()
    e.page.go("/home")
    
btn= ft.FilledButton(
                text="Go to home",
                width=120,
                height=40,
                 on_click=lambda e: page_nav(e) )

def _view_():
    return ft.View(
        "/index",
        controls=[
        ft.Column(
        controls=[
            ft.Container(
                width=120, 
                height=120, 
                bgcolor=f'#{rand_clr}',
                content=Text("Index Page")),
                
        ]
    )])
```

Answer (score 0):

make use of the `ft.after()` function, which schedules a function to be called after a specified delay.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried using the ft.after but has got error: AttributeError: module 'flet' has no attribute 'after'